# Keras Conv2D layer outputs array filled with NaN

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I built a keras model that takes an image as input and performs several convolutions and a pooling operation, then performs a specialized convolution layer with pre-initialized weights. When run on an image, this model outputs an array of the correct shape, but with all the elements as NaN.
The first part of the model is the first "block" of the pretrained [VGG16](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/vgg16.py) model for keras. The specialized layer (keras.layers.Conv2D) takes its weights as a set of filters corresponding to certain features I want to extract from the image. It does not matter if i flip the filters (to do cross-correlation), or if i change the image, always NaN. Any ideas?

EDIT: here is code. Takes a numpy image array as input.

```
def make_model(features, layer_name="block2_conv1"):
    vgg = VGG16(include_top=False)
    layer = vgg.get_layer(layer_name)
    x = layer.output
    num_chars, char_w, char_h, char_filters = features.shape
    filters = features.transpose((1, 2, 3, 0)).astype(int)
    filters = filters / np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(filters), axis=(0, 1), keepdims=True))
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    specialized_layer = Conv2D(num_chars, (char_w, char_h))
    x = specialized_layer(x)
    biases = np.zeros((num_chars, ))
    specialized_layer.set_weights([filters, biases])
    model = Model(inputs=vgg.input, outputs=x)
    return model
```

Comment: did you check for NaN in your input?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I did check for NaN in my input. It is just a numpy array corresponding to an image

Comment: I posted my code.